# use of undeclared identifier 'glGenVertexArrays' error even after including OpenGL/gl3.h in OSX 10.8.5

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, sdl

I'm opening an OpenGL context using SDL in OSX 10.8.5.

I've already run some tutorials that draw lines/triangles etc. I then started trying the more modern tutorials at www.open.gl

I'm running into trouble with the OpenGL 3+ API. I already include gl3.h in my headers:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
```

I get a warning, which is expected since I think the sdl headers open `gl.h`. That's okay, but the problem is that the but the compiler still reports that `glGenVertexArrays` as undefined even though gl3.h is included, saying `error: use of undeclared identifier 'glGenVertexArrays' glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);`

Comment: Did you miss a namespace specifier? Did you mean a linkage error?

Comment: it's a compiler error. I don't think any namespace specifier is needed for opengl.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe I've seen this problem myself.  I had to add an ifdef statement in one of my headers

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#define glGenVertexArrays glGenVertexArraysAPPLE
#define glBindVertexArray glBindVertexArrayAPPLE
#define glDeleteVertexArrays glDeleteVertexArraysAPPLE
#endif
```

Also, you should be including *either* the SDL OpenGL header or the native system header.  However, if you want to use the SDL OpenGL header, you should problaby do it like this

```
#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES 1
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
```

or you'll only get the older OpenGL 1.x functions.

Comment: That doesn't seem right to me for modern OS X software. Prior to the introduction of core profiles in 10.7, the APPLE extension for VAOs was the proper thing to use (Apple invented VAOs after all). However, Apple has implemented the core version of VAOs for several years now. This trick should be based on the renderer targeted (e.g. legacy 2.1 or core 3.2+) and not whether `__APPLE__` is defined. Since `<OpenGL/gl3.h>` is being included, it is safe to conclude that a core 3.2+ profile is being targeted.

Comment: this is bizarre, why the APPLE suffix?

Answer (score 8):

You don't have to include `SDL_opengl.h`, just include :

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl3ext.h>
#endif
```